# How to play a live video on youtube?

Tags: c#, uwp

When playing any video from YouTube you have no problem, however I have problems trying to play a live video

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <MediaElement Name="Media"
                  AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    </MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

I am using the package MyToolkit.Extended

```
    public async void SetDataPlayer()
    {
        _loadAnimationListener?.FinishLoadAnimation();
        var videoURL = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("DU5u4oCR8l0", YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
        Media.Source = videoURL.Uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to play a live video on youtube?

You could use [`CreateFromUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromuri) to converter YouTube video uri to `MediaSource` like the follow.

```
public async void SetDataPlayer()
{
    _loadAnimationListener?.FinishLoadAnimation();
    var videoURL = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("Bey4XXJxxxxx", YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
    Media.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(videoURL.Uri);
}
```